# LINQ - Calling Filter with a Predicate<T>

Tags: c#, linq

I would like to offer in one of my classes a way of filtering some elements. To keep my interface as clean and self-explanatory as possible, I want my filter property to be a `Predicate<T>`.

Here's a stripped-down example of my class:

```c#
public class ObjectAdapter
{
    public ObjectAdapter()
    {
        MemberFilter = DefaultFilter;
    }

    public Predicate<PropertyInfo> MemberFilter { get; set; }

    public virtual bool DefaultFilter(PropertyInfo info)
    {
        if (info.Name != "Test")
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

My idea is that people can easily set `MemberFilter` to whatever they want and thus there is no need to make a class that inherits from mine and overrides the `DefaultFilter` function.

**The problem:**

Inside my `ObjectAdapter`, if I try to do

```c#
something.GetType().GetProperties().Filter(MemberFilter)
```

I get this strange compilation error:

```
Error: cannot convert from 'System.Predicate<System.Reflection.PropertyInfo>' to 'System.Func<System.Reflection.PropertyInfo,bool>'
```

This makes no sense to me, since `MemberFilter` is basically a `delegate bool Predicate<PropertyInfo>(PropertyInfo obj)` which should be the same as a `Func<PropertyInfo, bool>`, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use `Func<PropertyInfo, bool>` and `Where` instead since you can't auto cast `Predicate<PropertyInfo>` into `Func<PropertyInfo, bool>`:

```
public class ObjectAdapter
{
    public ObjectAdapter()
    {
        MemberFilter = DefaultFilter;
    }

    public Func<PropertyInfo, bool> MemberFilter { get; set; }

    public virtual bool DefaultFilter(PropertyInfo info)
    {
        if (info.Name != "Test")
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

And

```
var oa = new ObjectAdapter();
var props= something.GetType().GetProperties().Where(oa.MemberFilter);
```

A different option would be to create a `Func<PropertyInfo, bool>` out of a `Predicate<PropertyInfo>`:

```
public class ObjectAdapter
{
    public ObjectAdapter()
    {
        MemberFilter = DefaultFilter;
    }

    public Predicate<PropertyInfo> MemberFilter { get; set; }

    public virtual bool DefaultFilter(PropertyInfo info)
    {
        if (info.Name != "Test")
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

And

```
var oa = new ObjectAdapter();
Func<PropertyInfo, bool> func = new Func<PropertyInfo,bool>(oa.MemberFilter);
var props = something.GetType().GetProperties().Where(func);
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that, while `Predicate<T>` and `Func<T,bool>` for the same type `T`, have the same signature, they are still different (and hence incompatible) delegate types. The problem can be solved by using `Func<T,bool>` instead of `Predicate<T>`, as there is no way to directly convert between them.

Comment: Okay, but how come the compiler is capable of converting `public virtual bool Filter(PropertyInfo)` into a `Func<PropertyInfo, bool>`. If I put `DefaultFilter` instead of `MemberFilter` in there, it works without problem. Even stranger to me, it successfully casts `Filter(PropertyInfo)` to `Predicate<PropertyInfo>` but then fails to cast `Predicate<PropertyInfo>` into `Func<PropertyInfo, bool>`

Comment: @FlorianSegginger That's because method groups *do* have conversions. Under the hood, you'll see it explicitly does something like `new Predicate<PropertyInfo>(DefaultFilter)` or `new Func<PropertyInfo, bool>(DefaultFilter)` respectively. There aren't conversion between *delegate types*, but method groups aren't delegates (yet) :)

Comment: That's because `public virtual bool Filter(PropertyInfo)` can be assigned to both `Predicate<PropertyInfo>` and `Func<PropertyInfo,bool>` as the desired signatures match; nevertheless `Func<PropertyInfo,bool>` cannot be assigned directly to `Predicate<PropertyInfo>`. I also found this confusing when I first came across it.